# Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion when using base_convert on Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have a problem with base_convert function on PHP,
I'm trying to make a unique ID for my primary key,

here is my code

```
base_convert(microtime(false), 10, 36)
```

but always showing error like this

```
Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored
```

I'm using Codeigniter 4 with PHP 7.4.29

Comment: Try `base_convert((string) microtime(false), 10, 36)`

Comment: Quote manual: _"By default, microtime() returns a string in the form `msec sec`"_ - so that is something like `0.01390300 1656571695` - which of course can't be interpreted as a number with base 10.  And even if you pass `true` as parameter, you will still get a _float_ value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses,
I already fix it using

```
$cleanNumber = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', microtime(false));
base_convert($cleanNumber, 10, 36)
```